# To access object properties based on the id present in an array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular7

I have 2 api's called `teachers` and `sessions`.

`teachers` **JSON** file:

```
[
      {
        "teacherName": "Binky Alderwick",
        "id": "01"
      },
      {
        "teacherName": "Basilio Gregg",
        "id": "02"
      },
      {
        "teacherName": "Binky Alderwick",
        "id": "03"
      },
      {
        "teacherName": "Cole Moxom",
        "id": "04"
      }
    ]
```

`sessions` **JSON** file:

```
[
    {
        "id":"001",
        "sessionName": "Chemistry",
        "notes": "Chemistry is the study of matter, its properties",
        "teacherIds": ["01","03"]<==========
    },
    {
        "id":"002",
        "sessionName": "Physics",
        "notes": "Physics is the natural science that studies matter and its motion ",
        "teacherIds": ["02","04"]
    },
    {
        "id":"003",
        "sessionName": "Maths",
        "notes": "Mathematics includes the study of such topics as quantity",
        "teacherIds": ["01","04"]<=========

    },
    {
        "id":"004",
        "sessionName": "Biology",
       "notes": "Biology is the natural science that studies life and living organisms",
        "teacherIds": ["02","04"]
    }
]
```

Now i am displaying all the teachers in the template like this:

[image]

In the **sessions** JSON, I have mentioned the **teacherIDs** which is of array, I want to display the sessions of the particular teacher based upon the teachersID.

For ex the sessions (Chemistry & Maths) contains **teacherID** as (01),So i want to display these 2 sessions(Chemistry & Maths) under **Teacher 1(i,e Binky Alderwick)** Like this:

[image]

I should get all the properties of the `session` object based on the `teacherId`.

[**Stackblitz DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-jdgdbq?file=src/assets/sessions.json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manipulate your `JSON` for the same like below -

```
getManipulatedData() {
    this.teachers && this.teachers.forEach(res => {
      res['subjects'] = [];
      this.sessions.forEach(obj => {
        if (obj['teacherId'].includes(res.id)){
          res['subjects'].push({subject: obj.sessionName, notes: obj.notes})
        }
      });
    });
  }

<h4>Teachers</h4>
<div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let teacher of teachers">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>{{teacher.teacherName }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sessions</td>
        <td><br>
    <div *ngFor='let subject of teacher?.subjects'>
      <h2>{{subject?.subject}}</h2>
      <p>{{subject?.notes}}</p>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>   
    <hr>
</div>
```

## [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-r67okl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

## Update -

Also you need to call this method on API call end like this -

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getContacts()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.teachers = res;
        this.getManipulatedData();
      });
    this.myService.getWorkers()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.sessions = res;
        this.getManipulatedData();
      });
  }
```

Comment: in your working example you are taking all the contacts using get contacts. But i want to get session for one particular teacher id = "01" i don't want to take all the contacts.

Comment: I showed the way you can do, you can customise accordingly

Answer (score 2):

This works in your stackblitz

```
<h4>Teachers</h4>
<div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let teacher of teachers">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>{{ teacher.teacherName }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>Sessions</td>
  <div *ngFor="let session of sessions">
    <span *ngFor="let id of session.teacherId">
      <span *ngIf="id == teacher.id">
        <h2>{{ session.sessionName }}, {{ session.id }}</h2>
        <p>{{session.notes}}</p>
      </span>
    </span>
    </div>
  </tr> 
    <hr>
</div>
```

Dont forget to remove the arrows from your JSON before putting this in.